# Disturbance with php code

Tags: php

Below code shows error

```
$th= $row['url']; 
//where $row['url']  it contains url///

$get_url = $th; 
$url = trim($get_url);
```

This is also showing error. How to fix it?

While the below code does not show any error and working fine.

```
$get_url = $_POST ['url'];
$url = trim($get_url);
```

The above code which is showing error.
Can any one fix it?

Comment: in your first code $u is not a string use $u = "http://example.com/xyz.png"; and you don't need $get_url you could directly use $url = trim($u);

Comment: you can also include any errors you get in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

In php you need to wrap strings in quotation marks, as well as indicate the end of line with a `;`

```
 $u = "http://example.com/xyz.png";
```

The reason the code on the bottom doesn't give an error is because php will wrap the result of the POST in quotes by default, as it gets handled like a string.

Comment: $th= $row['url']; ///where it contains url $get_url = $th; $url = trim($get_url);                   this is also showing error

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is with the above comment?